# Memory management issues between InnoSetup and Delphi DLL

Tags: delphi, memory-management, dll, themes, inno-setup

Situation:

- a DLL that:

  - is written and compiled with Delphi XE3 32bit
  - exports a function that displays a modal VCL-form:
    `function EditOptions(AIniFileName: PAnsiChar; ALCID: Integer): Boolean; stdcall;`
  - is also a COM-server
- an installer created with InnoSetup 5.5.4:

  - imports said DLL function via `external 'EditOptions@files:mydll.dll stdcall'`-directive and calls it when needed
  - explicitly unloads the DLL before registering the COM server via the Inno utility function `UnloadDLL`

Problem:

- When...

  - Windows is using a theme other than Classic
  - the modal dialog from the DLL is displayed during installation
- the installer hangs upon unloading the DLL
- no error messages are shown
- logs indicate no runtime exceptions

*Please note that to keep this brief, I deliberately left out the explanations for some of the more idiosyncratic details, e.g. why I'm explicitly unloading the DLL or why a COM server needs to have custom exports. Let me know if you think these details would be relevant and should be added.*

To further analyse this I created a dummy host EXE that calls the DLL function so I can easier run the whole thing in the debugger. Doing so leads to an AV being raised in `TUxThemeStyle.UnloadThemeData` on the line that calls `CloseThemeData()`. When placing a breakpoint directly on that line and stepping forward from the stop, I actually get a "too many consecutive exceptions" error eventually. I can only reproduce the error when I enable runtime themes for the host EXE.

Going back through our git history it appears that this issue exists ever since we switched from Delphi 2010 to XE3 (unfortunately, the installer was not part of our regular test suite so this only cropped up now as work on the actual release comes to a close as the DLL exports exist exclusively for the benefit of the installer).

Any ideas what might be causing this? Could this really be theme-related (I have no custom theme-related code in this project) or is that maybe just a symptom of memory corruption caused somewhere else entirely? E.g. I once had an error that manifested in the form of AVs in the theme tear-down code before but in that case it actually turned out to be caused by the leaking of anonymous method references from `initialization` sections...

**Update:** I've worked hard trying to produce a dumbed-down sample project to demonstrate the issue in isolation but so far without luck. I have managed to narrow down a few more things, though. First, here are some more facts about the code:

- The dialog I'm showing is a third-degree descendant of `TForm`. The ancestors accomplish several things:

  - `TAppModalDialog` implements a special constructor `CreateOnTop` that ensures it appears as the topmost window in the current process (the project is a plugin that loads into multi-windowed third-party hosts that do unfortunately not communicate their window handles for use as modal parents) - it accomplishes this by manipulating the global `Application.Handle`.
  - `TTabbedDialog` is part of an interface-based framework that allows registration of "pages" (actually `TFrame`-descendants) via a factory pattern - at runtime the form will dynamically create `TTabSheet`s in a `TPageControl` and instantiate and parent the registered page frames to them

I've replaced the call to the actual dialog with a dummy, gradually working myself through the inheritance chain from a blank `TForm` up to my `TAppModalDialog` and eventually to my `TTabbedDialog` class. The problem only starts to occur at that last level. I also commented out all page registrations around the project so that the dialog comes up with an empty page control (this rules out code in any of the pages as the cause for the problem). I then commented out all code and data members in the routines of the `TTabbedDialog` class itself, leaving only empty method bodies to fulfill the interface implementation requirement and the `TPageControl` component (along with two empty `TImageList`s and a `TBalloonHint` component) -> the error still occurs.

I then copied the call to the dummy dialog into a new DLL project that contains nothing else but this and the tabbed dialog framework. If I load that DLL into my dummy host EXE, the problem does **not** occur anymore... *sigh*

So, my suspicion is still that there must be some sort of memory corruption occuring somewhere else entirely and the error I see is only a symptom of that. So the real question is how can I finally get to the bottom of this?

I will now continue by commenting out / removing bits from the production DLL...

Comment: I'd like to know why you use sharemem. I think you should not be doing so. It would also be good to see the implementation of the exported function.

Comment: @David : It was actually mainly a workaround obtained by much trial and error for an issue with resourcestrings in Sisulizer-produced i18n-DLLs. However, I just tried again without sharedmem and the issue described here appears to be unaffected by this (probably should have done that test before posting so I could have left that detail out entirely).

Comment: As for the exported function: Do you mean the actual implementation or just the signature? The implementation is unfortunately not entirely straight-forward: The dialog I'm showing is a custom `TForm`-descendant with a `TPageControl` on it, which dynamically loads its pages at runtime via a registration mechanism...

Comment: Start with the signature.

Comment: @David: Done. Nothing spectacular, though...

Comment: No need for `Sharemem`. Definitely remove it. I think it would help if we could see your host exe and a cut down DLL.

Comment: Are you actually destroying the dialog properly before you try to unload the DLL?  Do you have any background threads in the DLL that might still be running code?

Comment: @Miral: Yes, there's a class method with the typical `Create; try ShowModal; finally Free`-construct.

Comment: As for background threads: Nope.

Comment: Alright folks, I figured it out and would now actually opt to close this if there were a close-reason like "too specific"... Turns out that a unit that was being pulled in via several layers of indirection still contained some old code that was intended as a workaround for a pre-XE2 VCL-bug: Simply put, it consisted of an explicit call to `FreeThemeLibrary` in the `finalization`-section... D'Oh!